# Loading LaTeX packages

Tags: support, mathjax

Is it possible to load a LaTeX package and/or use its features on this site? In my case, I'd need to load `multirow` to make block matrixes. Is that possible? Or is there a way to make a block matrix without `multirow` on this site? If so, which is it?

Comment: Related (perhaps a duplicate?): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/what-latex-packages-are-used-this-site

Comment: Of course, only the first part of your question can be considered a duplicate of the link I have provided. The second one (emulating multirow with MathJax) is not. I will [add a link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Columns_spanning_multiple_rows), illustrating what multirows does. (So that the people who do not know this package can see what you are trying to achieve.)

Comment: It is, perhaps, bad form, but you could do the table in $\LaTeX$ and the load it here as an image. This is what you have to do it you want to draw a picture.

Comment: You may find [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9671/perspective-to-equip-mathstackexchange-resources-to-the-creation-of-diagrams-suc) interesting too.

Comment: :grumble: posts like this is why I keep telling people _we don't use LaTeX on this site. We use MathJax, which just happens to use mostly the same syntax as LaTeX._